# Преобразовать многомерный массив в одномерный PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [came ati 3000] => 417
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [came ati 3000 купить] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [came ati 3000 цена] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [came ati 3000 цена] => 84
    )

)
```

Нужно преобразовать в такой одномерный:

```
Array
(
    [came ati 3000] => 417
    [came ati 3000 купить] => 0
    [came ati 3000 цена] => 0
    [came ati 3000 цена] => 84
)
```

Пробовал так:

```
$arrOut = array();
foreach($arrIn as $subArr){
$arrOut = array_merge($arrOut,$subArr);
}
```

или

```
$arrOut = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrIn);
```

... но при таких вариантах сливаются в одно все с одинаковыми значениями, таким образом:

```
Array
(
    [came ati 3000] => 417
    [came ati 3000 купить] => 0
    [came ati 3000 цена] => 84
)
```

, а мне необходимо получить все элементы в новый одномерный массив!

Comment: у массива не может быть два одинаковых ключа

Comment: @splash58 я понял ... ... тогда подскажите как быть в моей ситуации мне изначально нужно было сравнить числовые значения в строках и если текст совпадает, то оставить  ту которой цифровое значение больше нуля... я для этого и поместил строки в массив разбив на пары ключ => значение чтобы сравнить значение и убрать не нужное

Comment: а если ключ  есть только с нулевым значение, все равно удалить? и что делать, если несколько ненулевых значений?

Comment: @splash58 если только с нулевым то оставляем.. если есть дубль с большим нуля то оставляем его. Смысл такой: Я получаю фразы, проверяю каждую содержит ли фраза слово "купить" или "цена" если  нет то создаю дубль с нулевым значением ... так перебираю все.. а затем надо сделать то что я описал в первом предложении этого комментария.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrOut = array();
foreach($arrIn as $subArr){
  // разберем подмассив на ключи и значения
  foreach($subArr as $key => $val){
    // если значение с таким ключом существует, и оно больше текущего, то ничего не делаем
    if(isset($arrOut[$key]) && $arrOut[$key] > $val) continue;
    // добавляем значение во внешний массив
    $arrOut[$key] = $val;
  }
}
```